# Equality in distribution involving a uniform random variable and quantile function

Tags: probability, distributions, uniform-distribution, quantiles

I'm trying to show the following statement:

**"if $U$ is a random variable with uniform law over $[0,1]$, then $Q^2(U)$ has the same law as $X^2$"**.

Here $Q(x)=\inf\{z\in\mathbb{R}:P(\lvert X\rvert>z)\leq x\}$ denotes the quantile function of the random variable $\lvert X\rvert$.

**My thoughts**

Let $F_W(x)=P( W\leq x),$ $W$random variable. I understand that $$F_{Q(U)}(x)=P(Q(U)\leq x)=P(U\geq P(\lvert X\rvert>x))=1-F_U(P(\lvert X\rvert>x))=F_{\lvert X\rvert}(u),$$
that is, $Q(U)$ has the same law as $\lvert X\rvert$.  How to argue that  $[Q(U)]^2$ has the same law as $ X^2$?

**Reference**: [Rio's book, pp. 10](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783662543221)

**My Attempt (update)**

If $x<0$, then $P(Q^2(U)\leq x)=P(\emptyset)=P(X^2\leq x)=0$. So we can assume $x\geq 0$. Further, by detinition, $Q(u)\in(0,+\infty]$ if $u\in[0,1)$ and $Q(u)=-\infty$ if $u=1$. Then, given any $x\geq 0$,
\begin{align}
P(Q^2(U)\leq x)&=P(\lvert Q(U)\rvert \leq \sqrt{x})\\
&=P(\{Q(U)\geq -\sqrt{x}\}\cup\{Q(U)\leq \sqrt{x}\}) \quad (a)
\end{align}
By the comment above, $\{\omega:Q(U)(\omega)\geq -\sqrt{x}\}=\{\omega:Q(U)(\omega)>0\}$, and also
\begin{equation}
P(\{Q(U)>0\}\cup\{Q(U)\leq \sqrt{x}\})=P(\{Q(U)\leq \sqrt{x}\}\setminus\{U=1\})\quad (b).
\end{equation}

Hence, from $(a)-(b)$,
\begin{align}
P(Q^2(U)\leq x)&=P(Q(U)\leq \sqrt{x})+P(\{Q(U)\leq \sqrt{x}\}\cap\{U=1\}) \\
&=P(Q(U)\leq \sqrt{x})=P(U\geq P(\lvert X\rvert>\sqrt{x}))\\
&=1-F_U(P(\lvert X\rvert^2>x))=F_{ X^2}(x),
\end{align}
since $\{U=1\}$ has probability measure zero (absolute continuity of $U$) and applying well known results of the quantile function ([Galois inequalities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantile_function)).

Can you give me feedbacks about this proof?

Comment: Hint: $U$ and $1-U$ have the same law.

Comment: @whuber I'm trying to use your hint, but still didn't find a reasoning. Can you say more?

Comment: @whuber I will appreciate if you give me feedbacks about the above proof.

Comment: What is your random variable $X$? It is never defined!